# if statement within for loop running time

Tags: python, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have a for loop iterating through a list with n elements, and within the list, I have an if statement, like so:

```
for item in list:
    if item == match:
        item = 'found'
```

My teacher says that this code is in ϴ(1). How is it not ϴ(n)? The loop is forced to iterate through n elements, why is the code in ϴ(1)? Is it perhaps an error on my teacher's part?

Comment: edited, thank you for the correction

Comment: ,..  i think he meant the best case will O(1), worst case O(n)

Comment: Three possibilities: a) You made the same typo with your teacher (in which case the loop exits in the first iteration, thus ϴ(1)); b) If `list` is constant (i.e. feature of the algorithm rather than dynamic input), then complexity doesn't scale with input, so ϴ(1). c) Your teacher is mistaken.

Comment: best case complexity is theta(1), but worst case complexity is O(n) for this for loop.

Comment: To elaborate on b): if you input `match` as a nucleotide, and you have `list` of all nucleotides and want to check that the input is a valid nucleotide, that is ϴ(1), even though you do iterate through a list of four elements.

Comment: What are you expecting this to do? `item = 'found'` is just going to rebind the `item` variable, which will immediately be rebound to the next element from the `list`. If your teacher wrote this code (which also uses `list` as the name of a list, which is a terrible idea)… maybe we shouldn't be trying to guess how your teacher could be interpreted charitably, and instead just tell you to start learning on your own outside class…

Comment: @MohanBabu Theta(1) inherently means the asymptotic growth is always constant. Not best case, always. (Maybe you're thinking Omega(1)? But _everything_ is Omega(1), so that's not very useful.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities here.

1. Your teacher is pulling the classic, and supremely slimy, "we know the size of the list" trick.  This is a trick I have seen some smug individuals pull in which they claim that because `n` is known, `n` is a constant, ergo `n` is basically `~ 1`.  This is silly, bad logic, but it is something which some people fall back on sometimes.
2. Your teacher is simply mistaken.
3. Your teacher meant "best case" run-time, in which case the more precise statement would be `Ω(1)`, if I remember my Greek correctly.  But even this is wrong due to the lack of a break statement of any sort to exit the loop when the condition is met.

Comment: If the teacher meant best-case, the teacher is still wrong. This loop always does N `__next__` calls on the iterator and N `__eq__` comparisons, no matter what—there's no `break` or anything else to prevent it (unless the first `__eq__` raises an exception or segfaults or something, which would go even beyond slimy trick question territory).

Comment: Excellent point! So we agree then, in all cases the teacher is wrong.

Comment: However, it _is_ still `Ω(1)`, because `Ω(1)` doesn't mean best case. `o` vs. `O` vs. `Θ` vs. `Ω` vs. `ω` is a separate distinction from best vs. average vs. worst. Whichever of those three you're talking about, `Ω(1)` is a weak lower bound: just means that the running-time function (whichever one we're talking about) grows asymptotically no slower than order 1. Which is true for every algorithm, so it's kind of a useless thing to say.

Comment: It sounds like your grasp of algorithms is superior to mine - if you have the time, maybe you should either edit my answer, or write your own, so that future readers don't have to go digging in the comments for this information.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above, it has nothing to do with whether the size is known, but if it changes with input. ϴ shows a relationship between size of input vs complexity of execution. If `n` is not affected by input, then `n` doesn't get to participate in ϴ. Not sure where you see bad logic here.